# how to reverse/inverse order of elements in a vector or a matrix in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a vector

```
a = 1:4
```

I want to get

```
[4 3 2 1]
```

Which matlab function should I use?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For a row use

```
fliplr(a)
```

for column use

```
flipud(a)
```

Comment: And more generally, you could use `flipdim(a,dim)`. Where `dim` is the dimension (`dim=1` flips rows, `dim=2` flips columns).

Answer (score 7):

another option is to use indexing

```
a(end:-1:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array you want to reverse is a range `a:b`, then it is much faster to use:

```
-(-b:-a)
```